# Android dont reach the "else" statement inside try catch

Tags: java, android

I'm working on this code, send an HTTP request with volley, and when i get the `json` response, i parse it and depend on what it give him i want to start different intent.
All work fine but i cant figure out why in the `ifelse` statement it don't reach the "else" side of the cycle, if the main part of the cycle don't match.
If the main cycleis satisfied the code work fine, otherwise i have this problem.
Here the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText etUsername;
    private EditText etPassword;
    private Button btnLogin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etUsername = findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Login();
            }
        });
    }

    private void Login(){

        String url = "http://myapytestingthisurlisfake/loginuser_module";


        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                Log.d("STATO HTTP", String.valueOf(response));



                 try {
                    JSONObject jresponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONObject state = jresponse.getJSONObject("0");
                    JSONObject result = state.getJSONObject("Stato Information");
                    String statoo = result.getString("Stato");

                    Log.d("RESULT ERROR", statoo);

                    if (statoo.equals("Error")){ //Here the code work everytime
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "stato è uguale da error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {//Here the code work never
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Statoo è diverso ad error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }



                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "La chiamata non è andata a buon fine", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("user","hello");
                params.put("password","there");
                params.put("secretKey","somerandomcode231231231231");
                params.put("username_utente", etUsername.getText().toString().trim());
                params.put("password_utente", etPassword.getText().toString().trim());
                return params;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: so, the value is always "Error" ?

Comment: Please post the `Log.d("RESULT ERROR", statoo);`

Comment: Yeah guys all work fine, i have all permissione, the https calls work too, but everytime i launch the app, the code dont reach the else side of the statement

Comment: @Nicola that is because the status is every time Error -> this kind of means all doesn't work fine

Comment: Have you debugged your code?

Comment: When the send a request with wrong params, the server send me a json with the "error" string, and then the statement is satisfied and the first block of code work, but if i send the right params, so ELSE here should work, dont work

Comment: post   `Log.d("STATO HTTP", String.valueOf(response));`

Comment: D/STATO HTTP: {"0":{"Stato Information":{"Stato":"Error","Info":"Username\/password Errati o Utente inesistente o Utente Disabilitato"}},"username_utente":"jjnj","password_utente":"jjn"}
D/RESULT ERROR: Error

Comment: Did you check what print the JSON? `System.out.println();`

Comment: `You just wrote result is `Error`. You code behave like expected. Find out why

Comment: Set a breakpoint and inspect the value of `statoo`.